# Why are CIE standard illuminant SPDs given as relative power?

Tags: radiometry

Why is CIE standard illuminant data given as *relative* power distribution, and not absolute? They are always normalized, usually so that the power at 560nm is 100. Seems like an unnecessary loss of information. You cannot, for example, tell how much brighter one illuminant is compared to another. Why are the SPDs not given in plain radiance units, that is, [image: W/(sr*m^3)] ?

[image: D65 SPD]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the luminosity function to get the brightness for any power of any given power spectrum. So you are correct that the spectrums are normalized, i.e. not comparable in brightness, you need the source wattage to get the brightness.